# Fluent nHibernate: Generic base class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Does somebody knows a Generic class for use with Fluent nHibernate 
that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, Equals, ==, !=

I would like to do :

```
public class MyEntity : EntityBase<MyEntity>
{
public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4));  /*OnPropertyChanged("Name");*/ }
        } private string _Name;
        public virtual double Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set { _Value = value; OnPropertyChanged(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4)); /*OnPropertyChanged("Value");*/ }
        } private double _Value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know any existing base class, but there is an alternative way to get what you want. See

http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged